# Anyone know of an online prayer calendar?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, calendar, internet

I'm looking for an online calendar that gives daily basic prayer information. This calendar would be geared towards someone who needs to know when the prayers are out of the ordinary, or letting them know when not to wear tefillin.

A basic guide for that day's prayer, including information such as:

- Today is a regular day, no special prayers added.
- Today is Rosh Chodesh, add half-hallel and Musaf Prayer for Rosh Chodesh.

Does such a resource exist? If not, is there something close? A print version, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ezrastorah.org/calendar5773.php?page=download

Or is that too advanced?

Comment: It's a good calendar, but too much information for what I'm looking for. it makes it harder to see at a glance what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Would the chabad website work? It lists practices and observances for each day.
http://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/day.asp?tDate=9/16/2012

Answer (score 1):

Kaluach (available for free download [here](http://www.aish.com/jl/hol/o/48970511.html), or demo [here](http://kaluach.net/month.php), tells you which days are different (and also gives tons of other information, like zmanim and daf yomi, etc.) but it doesn't say which prayers are different (though anyone could probably figure out a way to add that to the calendar). Artscroll's calendar (in print for $36, available [here](http://mesorahheritage.org/DeskDiary)) is probably the closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for the artscroll calendar. It doesn't mention tefillin, but it does have good information about the prayers.

Answer (score 0):

The Ezras Torah canendar is available online at ezrastorah.org. It tells you what to say in the davening for each day that is different.

Comment: [Shalom](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20172/1569) already suggested this